# Querying in 3 tables with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework-core, devexpress

With the code below, I can make transactions with data from 2 tables. How can I integrate a 3rd table into this code. I want to calculate the differences between the Total Amount in the KlinikFis table and the Amount in the KlinikKasaHareket table as KasaninAlacaklari. After the calculation process, I will display it as a column.

```cs
public object KasaListele(NetStokContext context)
{
    var result = context.KlinikKasalar.GroupJoin(context.KlinikKasaHareketleri , c => c.KasaKodu, c => c.KasaKodu, (kasa, kasahareket) => new
        {
            kasa.Id,
            kasa.KasaKodu,
            kasa.KasaAdi,
            kasa.YetkiliKodu,
            kasa.YetkiliAdi,
            kasa.Aciklama,
            KasaGiris = (kasahareket.Where(c => c.KasaKodu == kasa.KasaKodu && c.Hareket == "Kasa Giriş").Sum(c => c.Tutar) ?? 0),
            KasaCikis = (kasahareket.Where(c => c.KasaKodu == kasa.KasaKodu && c.Hareket == "Kasa Çıkış").Sum(c => c.Tutar) ?? 0),
            
            **KasaninAlacaklari = (kasahareket.Where(c => c.KasaKodu == kasa.KasaKodu && c.Hareket == "Kasanın Alacakları").Sum(c => c.Tutar) ?? 0) ,**
            Bakiye = (kasahareket.Where(c => c.KasaKodu == kasa.KasaKodu && c.Hareket == "Kasa Giriş").Sum(c => c.Tutar) ?? 0) -
            (kasahareket.Where(c => c.KasaKodu == kasa.KasaKodu && c.Hareket == "Kasa Çıkış").Sum(c => c.Tutar) ?? 0),
            

        }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

```cs
public class KlinikFis : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FisKodu { get; set; }
    public string FisTuru { get; set; }
    public string HastaKodu { get; set; }
    public string HastaAdi { get; set; }          
    public Nullable<decimal> ToplamTutar { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }
}

public class KlinikKasaHareket : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string FisKodu { get; set; }
    public string Hareket { get; set; }
    public string KasaKodu { get; set; }
    public string KasaAdi { get; set; }           
    public string HastaKodu { get; set; }
    public string HastaAdi { get; set; }
    public string HastaSoyadi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> Tarih { get; set; }          

    public Nullable<decimal> Tutar { get; set; }            
}

public class KlinikKasa : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string KasaKodu { get; set; }
    public string KasaAdi { get; set; }
    public string YetkiliKodu { get; set; }
    public string YetkiliAdi { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your entities and what you are trying to retrieve. The is no limitation how many tables used in queries, but without GroupJoin.

Comment: Can you show sample coding? What are your suggestions instead of GroupJoin?

Comment: I can, but I need your classes with navigation properties.

Comment: I updated the data you requested in the post.

Comment: You want to use 3 tables, but specified only 2 entities.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got distracted. I updated

Comment: As said: define navigation properties. You should hardly ever need explicit (Group)Join statements in EF LINQ queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not final query. I'm not good in Turkish, please explain which difference do you need and how to join (which fields) third table with this result.

```cs
public object KasaListele(NetStokContext context)
{
    var query = 
        from kasa in context.KlinikKasalar
        join h in context.KlinikKasaHareketleri on kasa.KasaKodu equals h.KasaKodu
        group h by new 
        {
            kasa.Id,
            kasa.KasaKodu,
            kasa.KasaAdi,
            kasa.YetkiliKodu,
            kasa.YetkiliAdi,
            kasa.Aciklama            
        } into g
        select new 
        {
            g.Key,
            
            KasaGiris = g.Sum(c.Hareket == "Kasa Giriş" ? c.Tutar : 0) ?? 0,
            KasaCikis = g.Sum(c.Hareket == "Kasa Çıkış" ? c.Tutar : 0) ?? 0,
            KasaninAlacaklari = g.Sum(c.Hareket == "Kasanın Alacakları" ? c.Tutar : 0) ?? 0,
        } into s
        select new 
        {
            s.Key.Id,
            s.Key.KasaKodu,
            s.Key.KasaAdi,
            s.Key.YetkiliKodu,
            s.Key.YetkiliAdi,
            s.Key.Aciklama,            

            s.KasaGiris,
            s.KasaCikis,
            s.KasaninAlacaklari,

            Bakiye = s.KasaGiris - s.KasaCikis
        };

    var result = query.ToList();

    return result;
}
```